# Google location setting dialogue showing multiple times

Tags: android, location

```
PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
```

> is there any way to check checkLocationSettings dialouge is showing already?
>   how to prevent dialouge showing multiple times

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the location permission and location service before showing the `Permission Dialog`.

**Check Location Permission**

```
public static boolean isLocationPermissionAvailable(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        return true;
    }

    return (context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}
```

**Check Location Service Enabled**

```
public static boolean isLocationEnabled(Context context) {
    // Check if Current Device's SDK Version is Kitkat (Android 4.4 = API 19) & above
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        int locationMode = 0;
        try {
            locationMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);
        } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return locationMode != Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF;

    } else {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) &&
                locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }
}
```

Comment: i was handing the same way, but the issue was broadcast receiver gets called many times, thanks for the input. i have fixed it